# Why is var_dump not formatting correctly in PHP7?

Tags: php, debugging, testing, formatting

I use var_dump to debug some php scripts locally where I have php 5.6 installed and it formats beautifully on all browsers.

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(WP_Post)[1173]
      public 'ID' => int 33
      public 'post_author' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'post_date' => string '2018-01-11 17:26:22' (length=19)
      public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2018-01-11 23:26:22'(length=19)
```

When I upload the same file to a production box with php 7, the output is there, but the format is gone! any reason or clue why this is happening?

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1162 (3) { ["ID"]=> string(2) "61" ["post_title"]=> str
```

Comment: I've noticed that I have XDebug installed locally where not remotely, could that be the reason?

Comment: Yes, it's almost certainly because of xdebug. In fact, if you view the page source on your local version, you'll probably see xdebug specific markup. `<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>`, etc. PHP 7 is not to blame, that's just a coincidence.

Answer (score 5):

That "beautiful" format is probably because of Xdebug.

But, you can always use `<pre>` tags.

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($var);
    echo "</pre>";
```

It's not the same, but will help.

And remember, Xdebug shouldn't be installed/activated on production environment.

Answer (score -1):

XDebug was the main reason!  Since I am using Amazon Linux with PHP7, XDebug is not installed by default, so as soon as you install XDebug, var_dump outputs the readable version of the text.